# Concatenate Column E and G data to Column M

Tags: vba

I would like to concatenate my data from Column E and G to Column M, starting from row 2 down to a varying (every month) number of rows

somewhat like m2=e2&g2 until there's no data to concatenate.

I'm looking for possible answers but, I still can't play with all the codes I have found here because I'm just starting to learn VBA coding. Thanks in advance for the help. :)

Comment: Please show *some* code, your best attempt. People on Stack Overflow are usually willing to *help* someone with their code but not to do it for them since this isn't a free coding service. Show us where you are stuck and we will help you out. If you don't have any code at all since you don't know where to start, I recommend working through a VBA tutorial.

Comment: As easy as pie `[m2:m9999] = [e2:e9999 & g2:g9999]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to use VBA if all you want to do is to concatenate two cells together - you could use the CONCATENATE worksheet function inside your worksheet.   Most of the worksheets functions can be used in VBA by appending 'Application.' to them but CONCATENATE isn't one of them.  In order to do what you want in VBA you can do something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub concatColumns()
  With Worksheets(1)
    Dim lastRow As Integer, i As Integer
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row

    For i = 2 To lastRow:
      .Cells(i, "M") = .Cells(i, "E") & .Cells(i, "G")
      .Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

The above assumes that you're using the 1st worksheet and also explicitly changes the format of each "M" column entry to text so that excel doesn't auto format the result.